# Often in negative sentences

Tags: adverbs

Do both sentences mean the same?  I am asking about BrE.

1. "We don't often try to make this dish".
   2."We try not to make this dish often"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't mean quite the same thing.

1. "We don't often try to make this dish".
   This means that our attempts to make this dish are infrequent, without any particular  sentiment about that.
2. "We try not to make this dish often."
   This means that we deliberately try not to make the dish frequently. That expresses a slight negative sentiment about making the dish.